# Looping through aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

For a tournament application, i have to output group standings and a knockout schedule. They have to alternate on one big LED TV. I managed to do that using an IFrame that spanned 100% of the page and using javascript to set the iframe source to another aspx page every 10 seconds.

This works but i creates an enormous memory leak. each time a page is loaded in the iframe, the Internet Explorer process grows with about 6mb. this results in a IE process of 1,5Gb and a crash of the window after about 1 hour.

Is there a better way to create something similar? do the cycling all in codebehind?

Thanx,

Cypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the need for the iframe? You could just have the page reload every 10secs with an onload script.

A more clever approach, might be to use AJAX to download only the data you need to display & update the page with that. You could then take a stage further & use something like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) to only update the screen when the data changes.

Comment: The page with the iframe on has the configuration of the cycling (what pages, time interval, ...). I can work around the iframe, no problem. But the pages i call, use asp.net dataview and a telerik control. I really need to populate the controls serverside.

Comment: You could break the page into fragments (if it works that way) & and use signalr to indicate when new data is available & that a page fragment should be refreshed. The page fragment can be generated serverside as you've indicated.

Comment: i was thinking about 2 place holders and showing/hiding them according to the time interval. I will also take a look at the SignalR and how i can add ajax to the picture. thank you for your pointers.